# php - case-sensitive function to count how many characters in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function that creates an array and count how many characters are in a string, the function is case-sensitive.

I can only use **foreach**

example:

```
var_dump(count_char("H e l l o")); 
// should returns array("H" => 1, "e" => 1, "l" => 2, "o" => 1)

var_dump(count_char("Hello World"));
// should returns array("H" => 1,"W" = 1, "d" => 1, "e" => 1, "l" => 3, "o" => 2, "r" = 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
function count_char($str) {
    foreach ($str as $key => $value) {
        return strlen($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: use an associative array, key for character and value for count. `str_replace` can help you get rid of spaces.

Comment: _"I can only use foreach"_ Can you clarify that? Surely you'll need _something_ besides foreach for this.

Comment: @Don'tPanic My assignement tells me to only use foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an associated array and just go though the string is the easiest way...

```
function count_characters($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $char_counter = Array();
    foreach($chars as $char) 
        if(!isset($char_counter[$char])) $char_counter[$char] = 1;
        else $char_counter[$char] += 1;
    return $char_counter;
}

print(json_encode(count_characters("Hello World"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n");
```

if you want to exclude everything but ASCII characters (`[a-zA-Z]`):

```
function count_characters($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $char_counter = Array();
    foreach($chars as $char) 
        if ((ord($char) >= 65 && ord($char) <= 90) || 
            (ord($char) >= 97 && ord($char) <= 122)) {
            if(!isset($char_counter[$char])) $char_counter[$char] = 1;
            else $char_counter[$char] += 1;
        }
    return $char_counter;
}

print(json_encode(count_characters("Hello World... test This"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n");
```

To just exclude spaces:

```
function count_characters($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $char_counter = Array();
    foreach($chars as $char) 
        if (ord($char) != 32) {
            if(!isset($char_counter[$char])) $char_counter[$char] = 1;
            else $char_counter[$char] += 1;
        }
    return $char_counter;
}

print(json_encode(count_characters("H e l l o  W o r l d"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n");
```

Comment: Is there a way to not make it count spaces?

Comment: edited to show how to exclude everything but ASCII characters (a-z A-Z)

Comment: I would stay away from using `str_replace` on whitespace, that is just wasteful operations, meaning it will loop thru replacing the whitespace, and then you loop though counting, why not just ignore in the one foreach loop...  the `ord` function just casts a char to int, super efficient, all ASCII char(s) are just numbers to a lookup table, so using there int value allows us to simply do a > or <;

Comment: probably because you have an older version of php you're using.  Edited to work in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_count_values to do the trick without looping.

$str = 'Hello World';
$str = str_replace(" ","",$str);
$chars = str_split($str);
$ret = array_count_values($chars);
print_r($ret);

Comment: How do you think str_replace, array_count_values, and str_split work? Just because the loop is in a function doesn't mean it is not looping.

Comment: This does not answer his question at all, the criteria is specific that he uses a **foreach** loop...

Comment: I said ALSO, as an alternative solution.

Comment: Again, it is not a solution to his question when his question specifically says "I can only use **foreach**."   Yes, it is an alternative way of counting specific chars in an array, but it is not a solution to his question because it does not use **foreach** which he specifically states he can only use.  Not sure what part of this you are missing.

Comment: The answers are not just for him, someone might like to see other solutions to same problem.  Problem involves counting chars so dont get smart ass.

Comment: @AndrewK While it is generally good to provide support within the confines of the question brief, this is one of those occasions when toeing the line prevents you from showing how the OP _should_ be performing this task -- with functions that are specifically designed for this task. Please take the time to format your reasonable answer so that it conforms with the expected quality of this site. Thank you. (Please continue to educate people when you answer questions. Often OPs don't know the best way to carry out a task; if you know a superior method, always share!)

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps in your task:

1. split the string into an array of characters.
2. filter out non-letters
3. tally the occurrences of each letter

(There are a few ways to do this, as you can see from the answers on your next question.)  Since there seems to be some stress on a `foreach()` loop for your assignment, I'll offer the following:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wg6sA))

```
function count_char($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);             // split the string between each character
    $result = array();
    foreach($chars as $char) {
        if (ctype_alpha($char)) {         // only store letters
            if (!isset($result[$char])) {
                $result[$char] = 1;       // instantiate the letter in the result
            } else {
                ++$result[$char];         // increment the tally for the letter
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(count_char("Hello World"));
```

---

That said, a regular expression can perform the first two operations in one shot:

```
$letters = preg_split('~[^a-z]*~i', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

And as AndrewK mentions `array_count_values()` is a logic/direct choice:

```
$counts = array_count_values($letters);
```